# Node.js serialport readline parser - response devided to each sign in new line

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, serial, readline, parser

I would need some help in resolving a node.js problem with serialport response on one computer with Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit.
On the beginning I can confirm that the hardware which I have connected answers correctly in for example minicom. On an ARM computer the `readline serialport` response works very good, every answer from serial port is everytime readable, but on the Ubuntu 18.04 machine, when I send for example

```
AT+CGPSPWR=1\n
```

the answer looks like this:

```
A
T
+
C
G
S
P
W
R
=
1

O
K
```

I have this issue only on one machine, but the most important for me. 
I tried to change the parser from readline to raw - got the same answer. 
Also installed another serialport version and still no luck.

I really have no idea how to resolve this issue.
The answer from serial port I've got via main serialport function (which works everywhere else for checking serial:

```
serialPort.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

And this is the response:

```
Node 10.12.0
"gps": "^0.4.8",
"parsers": "^0.1.1",
"readline": "^1.3.0",
"serialport": "^7.1.3"
```